# How to Convert Doc to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, doc, pdftk

Here is some background info. I'm on a shared linux server with hostgator.

I've looked at

- phplivedocx,
- pdftk,
- fpdf,
- SetaPDF-Merger API,
- Muhimbi PDF Converter,
- mbtPdfAsm,
- http://pdfmerger.codeplex.com/, and
- pdflib

to no avail.

My server setup either does not support the setup or the program does not do what I need.

I want to programmatically using php

- allow my users to upload .doc files,
- convert them to .pdf files,
- add either a background/watermark/stamp with my company logo/link to website on each page of the converted .pdf file,
- merge the converted .pdf file to an existing promotion .pdf file,
- save and store the completed file to the server/database using the original file name of the .doc file,
- and then email the file to my mailing list.

What are my options? Any suggestions...?

Comment: Suggestion a) would be to use a Windows server running Word.  It's the Word->PDF bit you'll struggle with on a linux box.

Comment: Conversion of `.doc` to `.pdf` appears to be possible via the OpenOffice API http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=128143

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into running OpenOffice in Headless mode? Here's a quick link I found that may get you in the right direction.

http://qugstart.com/blog/linux/openoffice-headless-mode-installation-word-doc-to-pdf-conversion/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider moving to a VPS in order to install your own modules, or ask hostgator if they'll install one for you.

The best I've seen so far is [Pruno](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05) for using the OpenOffice API in php - though this will likely be impossible on a shared hostgator server.

[Antiword](http://www.winfield.demon.nl/) converts word docs to plaintext or postscript, which seems pretty nice - though you'll have to detect which type of document it is as you'll have to process the doc using a different method if it's a docx...though once again, this will likely be impossible on a shared hostgator server.

You may want to consider getting a more programmer friendly host. [I use ChicagoVPS](https://billing.chicagovps.net/aff.php?aff=181) (the link is my affiliate link - [here's a non-affiliate link](http://chicagovps.net)) as they have pretty decent performance (my past linode boxes did seem a bit faster regarding CPU tasks), are often featured on [lowendbox](http://www.lowendbox.com/blog/chicagovps-7month-2gb-openvz-vps-in-buffalo-ny-and-chicago-il-usa/) and you can pretty much always get a 2GB of ram openvz box (from their chicago datacenter) for $7/mo (promo code: 2048).

I had my performance dip once for 2 days, but it was due to some hardware issues and maintenance, they notified me many times a day on the status, and promptly had it fixed so I've stuck with them.

If a vps is not for you, there's [webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com/) - an awesomely programmer friendly 'shared' host.

Answer (score 0):

If using a web-service is a viable option for your application have a look at [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) Cloud services.  From your requirement list:

1. upload doc - yes
2. produce pdf - yes
3. watermark - yes
4. merging - yes - but you'd have to provide a doc or odt version rather than pdf
5. store in db - your control (you would save the streamed result to the db)
6. email - yes

Access from PHP is pretty straight forward since you can just HTTPS post a request.  Please note I work for the company that develops Docmosis.

Comment: docmosis does not have support for php

Comment: @Andrei - sure it does, as per the last comment in my post.